# Limiting the maximum number of client connections in an NIO Selector

Tags: java, networking, selector, nio

I have an asynchronous NIO Server using a regular `java.nio.channels.Selector` that accepts clients (in non-blocking mode, i.e. I do `socketChannel.configureBlocking(false)` for each accepted client).

This works pretty well, but I have a concern that there appears to be no obvious constraint on the maximum number of client connections. I would like to limit these to control server resources and provide resilience against unexpected load / denial of service attacks etc.

Two related questions:

- What is the best practice for controlling the maximum number of client connections?
- Is there a way of doing this that is selective, e.g. some more critical clients get priority over others if the connection limit risks being breached?

Comment: Count them and stop accepting while there are >= your limit, i.e. deregister for OP_ACCEPT. There is no way of knowing prior to accepting the connection how important it is.